# Achieve Vlingo app like user interface in my application?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to design a UI in which i will be displaying large amount of text content followed by a single button. User cam scroll down the text content but the button should remain at the bottom of the screen visible all the time. Vlingo application available at android market uses similar kind of UI as show in figure below:

[image] [image]

I have tried putting the text content in a scrollView and button outside scrollView but doing this the button cutts off the screen. Here is XML layout i tried:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsgHd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/message"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"                                
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />           
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsg1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtMsgHd"
            android:text="@string/main_ex_msg1" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSpeak"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/speak_now" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think about using a listview to do this vs. a scroll with a lot of text views etc. but for the sake of just answering the question if all you are trying to do is make the scroll view not overlap or push down the bottom button I would do something like the following

NOTE: had to remove any resource references so it's kind of messy but you should get the idea

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_above="@+id/btnSpeak">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsgHd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Msg A"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"                                
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />       
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsgHd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Msg B"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"                                
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />           
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsgHd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Msg C"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"                                
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsgHd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Msg D"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"                                
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />     
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsgHd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Msg E"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"                                
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsgHd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Msg F"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"                                
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />   
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsgHd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Msg A"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"                                
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />       
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsgHd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Msg B"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"                                
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />           
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsgHd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Msg C"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"                                
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsgHd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Msg D"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"                                
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />     
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsgHd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Msg E"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"                                
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsgHd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Msg F"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"                                
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />                           
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMsg1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtMsgHd"
            android:text="Msg 1" />
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSpeak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Speak Now" />

</RelativeLayout>
```